# Reading an Excel object retrieved using urllib2

Tags: python, excel, urllib2, xlrd, xlwt

I am getting an Excel file using urllib2 and saving into response below. I want to be able to process this excel file using xlrd or similar. I included some info below, let me know if I can provide more info. How can I have response object transformed into an object I can play with?

```
response = <addinfourl at 199999998 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x100001010>>

response.read() prints: '\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0...'

Headers:
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `xlrd`, and based on [its API documentation](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html), it appears like you can use something similar to this:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=response.read())
```

It doesn't appear to support reading a `file` object (which, IMO, would be ideal), only taking in a `filename` itself or the above `file_contents` method.

If `file_contents` didn't exist or didn't work, you'd have to use [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) to write the response to a temporary file and read that.

Comment: Thanks, @zigg. When I first tried this, I had `xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=response)` but no `.read()` That was causing an error, `AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__len__'`